# selecting item from dropdown based on db record

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this `dropdown` in asp.net application `c#`. When I fetch a row from database I want the drop down to select corresponding value from `dropdown`. Like if I have saved my name in database and drop down contains list of names then upon search button click the drop down should show my name selected instead it over writes the initial item "Please select" and writes my name. and when I press search it shows `validator` "Please select a name" and I have to drop down and again select my name and then it proceeds.
Code:

```
 ddl_bank.SelectedItem.Text= dt.Rows[0]["BANK_NAME"].ToString();
```

here is the dropdown

```
            <label for="textfield">&nbsp;Bank Name</label>&nbsp;
            <asp:DropDownList Font-Size="Small" ID="ddl_bank" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
                AppendDataBoundItems="True"
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_bank_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Value="0" Selected="True" Text="Select Bank Name"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
                ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" InitialValue="0"
                ControlToValidate="ddl_bank" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Please select a bank"
                SetFocusOnError="True" Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Red">
            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to

```
ddl_bank.Items.FindByText(dt.Rows[0]["BANK_NAME"].ToString()).Selected = true;
```

Using `SelectedItem.Text` sets the text of the currently selected item in the `DropDownList` thus your experience on it being overwritten.

The code I provided first finds the corresponding item in the list by text (or by value by using `FindByValue` instead) and select it afterward.

You might receive an error that you can only have one item selected in a `DropDownList`, 
use `ddl_bank.ClearSelection();` before the code above

Comment: it says .FindItemsByText cannot be found

Comment: Updated it now.

Comment: Glad I could help! Good luck and don't hesitate to comeback for a question (in a new post of course). ;)

Comment: Sure :) You saved my job :)

Answer (score 0):

Use "SelectedValue" Property of DropDownList

Note: First you need bind Data to dropdonwnlist and then use "SelectedValue" for dropdownlist option selected.

```
ddl_bank.SelectedValue= dt.Rows[0]["BANK_NAME"].ToString();
```

Comment: okay i have binded the drop down now it has name of banks. when i first save my record i select a bank name from drop down. Now the next time i fetch my record i want it to select the value from dropdown which it fetches from db that was exactly my question. because my items have no value

Comment: Thankyou for your referral :)